# ASP.NET MVC 4 application routing not working in azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

i have a problem with an ASP.NET MVC application,this locally everything right, including the azure emulator, but after the publish into azure, the routing stoped to work and  i am getting this error

**No route in the route table matches the supplied values**

here is my routes into **RouteConfig**

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "Default2", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{urltoken}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", urltoken = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

this happens every time that i try to login, after the form submit the error appears..

Someone knows why the routing is not working into azure?

this is an image of the error:

!link image >[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Jsu.png)

**update:**

i was reading some posts talking about

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

and a will test this..

```
       <modules>
  <remove name="SessionAuthenticationModule" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

Comment: Remove the trailing slash in the first route `{controller}/{action}/` and move it to be the last registered route.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of checks that you can perform:

- Make sure that the copy local of MVC libraries are set to true. Following are the libraries that MVC looks for:

  System.Web.Abstractions.dll

  System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

  System.Web.WebPages.dll

  System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll

  System.Web.Razor.dll

  System.Web.Helpers.dll

  System.Web.Mvc.dll

  In fact, I'll suggest you to refer these assemblies from a folder in your solution.
- Second, you can also check for the following setting in System.webServer in the web.config:

  ```
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  ```

Comment: can you explain about runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests?